# Removing duplicate bigram having reversed words

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I am having following dict:

```
{'time pickup': 8, 'pickup drop': 7, 'bus good': 5, 'good bus': 5, 'best service': 4, 'rest stop': 4, 'comfortable journey': 4, 'good service': 4, 'everything good': 3, 'staff behaviour': 3, ...}
```

You can see that at index 2 and 3 having same words in each, I need to remove one of them, and removing meaningless word is recommended.

I am reversing the sentence and later I will remove one by checking if two matches.
But its complexity could be high if more words.

```
def remDups(s):
    words = s.split(' ') 
    string =[] 
    for word in words: 
        string.insert(0, word) 

    print("Reversed String:") 
    return (" ".join(string)).strip()
```

If anybody know efficient method, please help me out in this.

Comment: What do you mean by "meaningless word"? All the words in your dict have a meaning.

Comment: Its meaningless sentence 'bus good' -> and it is good if it makes 'good bus'.

Comment: semantically related.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the sentences by space and convert the result into a set. Since set are unordered, `{'bus', 'good'}` and `{'good', 'bus'}` will be compared as equal.

Comment: Sets are not hashable, so you can't keep them in the dict with frequencies.

Comment: @Jindřich Use frozenset instead : `frozenset(('bus', 'good'))`

Answer (score 1):

you can sort the words and make use of dictionary itself to ensure there are no duplicates

**Code**

```
def remDeps(s):
    return {" ".join(sorted(key.split(" "))):s[key] for key in s}
```

**Sample usage**

```
a = {'time pickup': 8, 'pickup drop': 7, 'bus good': 5, 'good bus': 5, 'best service': 4, 'rest stop': 4, 'comfortable journey': 4, 'good service': 4, 'everything good': 3, 'staff behaviour': 3}
remDeps(a)
```

**Output**

```
 {'pickup time': 8,
 'drop pickup': 7,
 'bus good': 5,
 'best service': 4,
 'rest stop': 4,
 'comfortable journey': 4,
 'good service': 4,
 'everything good': 3,
 'behaviour staff': 3}
```

Comment: Can we make 'bus good' to 'good bus' or 'behaviour staff' to 'behaviour staff'.

Comment: That would be a complete fore different problem to be handled differently.  Instead of the sorted join, you may call a different function that converts the string to one vaid form but to avoid duplicates as such this should be good